# Tap very quickly does not fired touchstart but click

Tags: javascript, events, touchstart

I do a test with three pages, on the first page I put a link to the second.
On the second page I have a link in the same position of the first page to do a fast flow and I have an event listenner on touchstart and on click.
If I click very fast and multiple times on the first link, the second link is clicked too (<300ms) but the ontouchstart is not fired, the onclick event is fired.

Do you know why ?
My assumption is that a click of the first page is posted on the second page

Comment: Hi, please provide a code sample for your question.